# mysql query on two tables

Tags: php, mysql

What SELECT query can i use to only show the `cars` WHERE `bookings`.`status` <> 1

so on the table below, `cars`.`id` (1, 3, 4, 6) will only show as the result

i'm stuck with this query or of this is any good:

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` as `C` INNER JOIN `bookings` AS `B` ON `C`.`id` = `B`.`id` ....?
```

`cars`

```
  id | name
  -- | -------------
  1  | Car 1
  2  | Car 2
  3  | Car 3
  4  | Car 4
  5  | Car 5
  6  | Car 6
```

`bookings`

```
id | car_id | status
-- | ------ | ------
1  | 1      | 0
2  | 2      | 1
3  | 2      | 2
4  | 1      | 0
5  | 5      | 1
```

EDIT: sorry i wasn't clear here, i also want the others listed as result even though they are not on the `bookings` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` as `C` INNER JOIN `bookings` AS
 `B` ON `C`.`id` = `B`.`id` where `B`.`status` <> 1
```

Try this if you didn't want records from Cars that are not in Bookings :

```
SELECT * FROM `Cars` as `C` Right JOIN `Booking` AS
 `B` ON `C`.`id` = `B`.`id`
```

Comment: this will give me the opposite result that i wanted to have, it will return the `cars`.`id`(2,5)

Comment: means you want to get the result where status equal to 1 ?

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear here, i mean it will only show me the list of `cars` that are `status` <> 1, in this case only the `cars`.`id` (1), i also want the others listed as result even though they are not on the `bookings` table

Comment: show me in comments what result you expect.did you try left join ?

Comment: yes and same result, basically it will only show the `cars` that are listed on the `bookings` table. for example the `car`.`id` 6, will not show on the result because it has no `bookings`.`car_id` 6.

Comment: solved it using this query `SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE `id` NOT IN  (SELECT `B`.`car_id` FROM `cars` AS `C` INNER JOIN `bookings` AS `B` ON `C`.`id` = `B`.`car_id` WHERE `B`.`status` = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

This will only show the cars

```
SELECT c.name FROM `cars` as `C` INNER JOIN `bookings` AS
     `B` ON `C`.`id` = `B`.`id` where `B`.`status` != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` C, `bookings` B WHERE C.id=B.car_id AND B.status!=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
SELECT * FROM cars C LEFT JOIN bookings B ON C.id = B.car_id  WHERE B.status <> 1
```

Comment: it will only show the cars that are listed on the bookings table. for example the car.id 6, will not show on the result because it has no bookings.car_id 6.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `car_id` from your `bookings` table is the same column as the `id` in the `cars` table...

```
SELECT A.* from cars A
inner join bookings B on A.id=B.car_id
where b.status<>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT with this query

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE `id` NOT IN  (SELECT `B`.`car_id` FROM `cars` AS `C` INNER JOIN `bookings` AS `B` ON `C`.`id` = `B`.`car_id` WHERE `B`.`status` = 1)
```

thanks everyone, it helped alot from your answers

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.* , B.* FROM cars A, bookings B WHERE B.car_id=A.id AND B.status <> 1
```